# parse html string in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

How to parse the HTML string in jquery?

I have two types of html tags and i want get text from these tags

I am not able select the tag for below given html string

The html is here

```
<p>
    <b><span>22:00</span></b>
    <span>
        <span>
            <b>ABCD</b>
        </span>
        <b> XYZ</b>
</span>
</p>
<p>
    <b><span >06:00</span></b>
    <span>
        <b>LMNOP</b> 
    </span>
</p>
```

and jquery code

```
$(html).each(function() {
    $(this).find('p').each(function() {
        $(this).find('b span').eq(0).each(function() {
        });

        $(this).find('span b').eq(0).each(function() {
            console.log($(this).text());
        }); 
    });
```

I want to select `ABCD` and `XYZ` in one shot, similarly `LMNOP`

i.e output should be `ABCDXYZ` and `LMNOP`

How can I select this in jQuery?

Comment: What does `html` represent? A jQuery object? The page itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to check that the selected element, the `b` tag, contains no child elements. Try this:

```
var $html = $("<p><b><span>22:00</span></b><span><span><b>ABCD</b></span><b> XYZ</b></span></p><p><b><span >06:00</span></b><span><b>LMNOP</b> </span></p>");

var $b = $html.find('b').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length == 0;
}).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());  
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3BG6/)

Answer (score 1):

I took a second look at your attempt and expected result and think I actually figured out what you are trying to do:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQNgz/2/)

```
$(html).find('p').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).find('span b').text());
});
```

Result (same as your expected "`ABCDXYZ` and `LMNOP`") :

> ABCDXYZ
>   LMNOP

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on the HTML *string* provided, **Try**:

```
$(html).each(function(){
    console.log( $('span b', this).text() );
});
```

**Outputs:**

```
ABCD XYZ
LMNOP
```

**Proof:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/mScSv/

With `$(html)` I converted the HTML string to a valid jQuery objects. In this case there are two root elements in the string, to paragraphs `p` so I could run each against it directly.

Note the space in the output as there is the same space in the HTML.

Comment: Criticising comments are not exactly constructive. Also, your code would break if the content of the `html` string changes.

Comment: Any jQuery selectors based on tag name alone would break if the content of the html changes. The OP has given us no other choice.

Comment: Tag names are less likely to change than the order they appear in. Also, it seems clear that the OP wants to exclude the `b` tags which contain `span` elements, not just the second, third and fourth `b` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Did a much cleaner selector and added proof.

Comment: Oh come on, you just completely removed your answer and copied the essence of mine after I posted. Also your `$('p')` wouldn't work as it appears that the OP has the html he is working on stored in a variable rather than on the document. Also you still have "`each()` isnt needed" while using it.

Comment: I did not initially read the question completely. I made **ass**umptions and didn't fiddle my code. I was only influenced by the other answers to read the question better and did not copy any code. The question was asked poorly and am still not entirely sure if the `HTML` referenced is a JavaScript variable or the actual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        here I assumed that the <b> tag contains alpha numeric characters or space
        for other characters regular expression should be changed.
        */
        var arr = $('body').html().match(/\<b\>[\sA-z0-9]*\<\/b\>/gi);
        var output = Array();
        var temp = '';
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var str = arr[i].replace('<b>', '');
            str = str.replace('</b>', '');
            temp += str;
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                output.push(temp);
                temp = '';
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            output.push(temp);
        }
        //the array output stores the required result
        for (item in output) {
            document.write(output[item] + '<br>');
        }

    </script>
```